# C# StreamReader fail, some garbage symbol showed

Tags: c#, https

```
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encode);
string ResponseJSON = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Here is part of my code.

I want create a https request then get the response string.

Actually my code work well when I didnt use proxy.

But when I use a https proxy, the program fail.

Then I checked in the debug mode, I found that the response string was something garbage symbol and characters. And this case did not happen when I did not use proxy.

It is a problem related to encoding ?? But I had used same encoding all the time , why only when I using a proxy the code not work?

Sorry for poor english,if anything unclear, please ask me to clarify.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

The encoding of an HTTP response is stored in the `charset` attribute of the `Content-Type` header. You can access it through the [HttpWebResponse.CharacterSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.characterset(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

It seems your proxy is changing the character set of the response to something else. You should check both `Charset` and the [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contenttype(v=vs.110).aspx) property to find the encoding it uses. Perhaps the proxy changed the character set to something else or it may even have compressed it.

You should check `Charset` before reading the stream eg:

```
if (response.CharacterSet!="utf-8")
{
....
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems the response is GZIP-compressed. To automatically decompress the stream you should set the [HttpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. This will add the proper headers to the request *and* automatically decompress the response, eg:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
var response=request.GetResponse();
var stream=response.GetResponseStream();
...
```

Comment: I found that the characterSet and contentType were UTF8 but the content encoding is gzip. Is the gzip cause the problem ?

Comment: This means that the response is compressed. You need to set `AutomaticDecompression` in the request to handle this